# Functional Contact Me Form - HTML or PHP problem?

Tags: html, css, preloader

Encountering a problem when trying to complete the contact form on my site, I'm finding error code 405 and not quite sure why. Whether it's a problem in my PHP or my HTML, can anybody help?

Site: https://loudburr.github.io/louisburr/
PHP:

```
    if (isset($POST['submit'])) {
$name = $POST['name'];
$subject = $POST['subject'];
$mailFrom = $POST['mail'];
$message = $POST['message'];

$mailTo = "*my email*";
$headers = "From: ". $mailFrom;
$txt = "You have received an e-mail from" .$name.".\n\n".$message;

mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers); 
header("Location: index.html?mailsend");'
```

Any help would be great!

Cheers!

Comment: Is your form method is POST?

Answer (score 0):

405 means "method not allowed". You are making a POST request and the server is telling you that you aren't allowed to make POST requests to that URL.

It isn't a PHP or HTML problem.

Your hosting service (Github pages) doesn't support **any** server-side programming features, so it doesn't support POST requests (or PHP).

Comment: Hey Quentin, thanks for reaching out. I was not aware of this, do you know how I may be able to get this contact form to function under Github or know an alternative method to getting my website hosted and have the PHP working?

Comment: "do you know how I may be able to get this contact form to function under Github" — Github. Does. Not. Support. Any. Server-side. Programming. Features.

Comment: "know an alternative method to getting my website hosted and have the PHP working?" — Use a hosting service with the features you need.